# Creating string array using Regex.Split

Tags: c#, regex

Alright, I'm warning you in advance, my understanding of Regular Expressions is extremely limited (I've tried my best to learn them over the years, but to be honest, I think they just frighten me.)

Let's say I have the following string:

```
string keyValues = "CustomerId=1||OrderId=12||UserId=a1dcd568-f129-419b-b51e-be2dbb67de0f"
```

This string represents key-value pairs, delimited by a user-defined string (in this case `||`) (e.g. `key1=value1||key2=value2`). I am trying to extract the keys out of this string and store them in an array. That array would look like this:

```
{"CustomerId", "OrderId", "UserId"}
```

The best option I can think of is to use regular expressions (If someone has a better solution, please share). Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
string delimiter = "||";
string[] keys = Regex.Split(keyValues, "=.*" + delimiter);
```

I may be wrong, but the way I understand it, that regular expression is supposed to find a string that starts with `=` and ends with `delimiter`, with any number of any characters in between. Which would split the string at those positions, leaving me with the original keys, but instead, my keys array looks like this:

```
{"", "C", "u", "s", "t", "o", "m", "e", "r", "I", "d", "", "", ...}
```

As you can see, the `=value||` part is stripped away. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

In my case, the delimiter `||` is a variable. I didn't mention this only because I thought I would be able to replace any references to `||` with `delimiter`. From the majority of the answers given, I now see that that is an important detail.

Comment: These two sites may be really helpful to understand Regular Expressions:
http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/admin_ee_cu/cm_regex.html and 

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @Billy: That [Postini](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/admin_ee_cu/cm_regex.html) page only covers the POSIX ERE flavor, which is extremely limited and incompatible with .NET regexes.  [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) uses the ActionScript flavor, which is more compatible but still sorely lacking in features.   **[This site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)** is much more useful, and MS's own **[docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx)** are pretty good.

Comment: @Alan Moore: You're absolutely right. I also get alot of information from the website you shared, but it's a whole load of information. I thought some explanation of the basics would be nice :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` has special meaning in regular expression (`patA|patB` matches either `patA` or `patB`). Escape `|`.

Using non-greedy match (`.*?`):

```
string delimiter = "||";
string[] keys = Regex.Split(keyValues, @"=.*?" + Regex.Escape(delimiter));
```

This will give you `{"CustomerId", "OrderId", "UserId=a1dcd568-f129-419b-b51e-be2dbb67de0f"}`.

`Matches` with lookahead assertion is more appropriate:

```
string delimiter = "||";
string keyValues = "CustomerId=1||OrderId=12||UserId=a1dcd568-f129-419b-b51e-be2dbb67de0f";
string pattern = @"(?<=^|" + Regex.Escape(delimiter) + @")\w+(?==)";
var keys = Regex.Matches(keyValues, pattern);
```

BTW, use verbatim string literals (`@"verbatim string literal"`) when express regular expression.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Brappw)

Answer (score 2):

If you just care for the keys, why not try to use a match instead of a split using:

```
@"[^=|]+(?==)"
```

If the key can't contain an equal sign `=` or a vertical bar `|`, then the above expression will match one ore more characters that are not `=` or `|` which are followed by an equal sign `=`, thus matching the keys.

In C#:

```
var input = "CustomerId=1||OrderId=12||UserId=a1dcd568-f129-419b-b51e-be2dbb67de0f";
var results = Regex.Matches(input, @"[^=|]+(?==)");
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to do this without a regular expression, as the string operations are pretty basic:

```
string[] keys =
  keyValues.Split(new string[]{"||"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
  .Select(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf('='))).ToArray();
```

Keep the regular expressions to the advanced string operations. :)

(When testing the performance of this solution compared to using a regular expression, this showed to be about 40 times faster.)

Answer (score 0):

Split on `@"=[^|]*(?:\|\||$)"`
If you need more assurance, use `@"=[^=|]*(?:\|\||$)"`

Edited to consume end where no delimeter exists.
Try to just use no-blank elements if its in C#.